# Fragment to access Interface

Tags: android, interface, fragment, retrofit

I have a bottom navigation with fragments.

The Fragments can't access RetrofitInstance interface.

unreachable Statment:

```
final IGDBApi igdbApi = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(IGDBApi.class);
```

Should I pass  `IGDBApi igdbApi` from Parent Activity  to the fragment via Bundles?

Is there another way to this ? Idk if this is correct.

Comment: no you should not. Instead you should fix the unreachable statement warning

Comment: idk whats wrong here tbh , i m new to fragments.

Comment: .. the statement is unreachable, has nothing to do with fragments

Comment: what part is wrong ? I mean it works inside activity, so I fail to understnad whats the problem here , I figured the fragment  jsut cant acces the interface just like a normal activity ?

Comment: you don't show the code so I can only guess that this line comes immediately after the call to `return super.oncreateview` in the fragment, making it unreachable

Comment: ahh thats right... thx.. fixed :D